# Set data attribute value to same elements other attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign the value of data attributes to the same elements srcset or src

```js
var is_chrome = (typeof window.chrome === 'object' && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1);

if ($('.image-browsers').length > 0) {

    if (is_chrome) {
         var a = $('.mobileImages').attr('data-mobileImage'),
         b = $('.desktop-images').attr('data-mobileWebp');
         $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', a.val());
         $('.desktop-images').attr('src', b.val());
    }
    else {
      var c = $('.mobileImages').attr('mobileImage'),
      d = $('.desktop-images').attr('desktopImage');
      $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', c.val());
      $('.desktop-images').attr('src', d.val());
    }
}
```

```html
<picture class="image-browsers">
  <isif condition="${mobileImage}">
    <source class="mobileImages" srcset="" media="(max-width: 768px)" data-mobileImage="test.jpg" data-mobileWebp="test2.webp">
  </isif>
  <isif condition="${desktopImage}">
    <img class="desktop-images" src="" alt="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }" title="${'previewName' in contentAsset.custom && contentAsset.custom.previewName != null ? contentAsset.custom.previewName : '' }"
      data-desktopImage="test3.jpg" data-desktopWebp="test4.webp">
  </isif>
</picture>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. If I remove val(), no error. If I add it, it shows error.

Comment: There's several issues here. 1) Don't use browser sniffing 2) `attr()` returns a string, so calling `val()` on that will raise an error 3) use `data()` to get data attributes, not `attr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked :

```js
if (is_chrome) {
         var a = $('.mobileImages').attr('data-mobileWebp'),
         b = $('.desktop-images').attr('data-desktopWebp');
         $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', a);
         $('.desktop-images').attr('src', b);
    }
    else {
      var c = $('.mobileImages').attr('data-mobileImage'),
      d = $('.desktop-images').attr('data-desktopImage');
      $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', c);
      $('.desktop-images').attr('src', d);
    }
```

Not sure why this didn't work:

```js
if (is_chrome) {
         var a = $('.mobileImages').data('mobileWebp'),
         b = $('.desktop-images').data('desktopWebp');
         $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', a);
         $('.desktop-images').attr('src', b);
    }
    else {
      var c = $('.mobileImages').data('mobileImage'),
      d = $('.desktop-images').data('data-desktopImage');
      $('.mobileImages').attr('srcset', c);
      $('.desktop-images').attr('src', d);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the data(...) function.

The .data(...) function returns an object (in this case string) wich is not a HTML Element and therefore has no val method. Look  [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

The .attr(...) function returns an object of type string, wich has no "val" method. [jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: OP isn't using `data()`. Also `data()` returns the same data type you placed in to it, not always a string. You seem to be confused with `attr()`

Comment: Thanks - i meant he should use data ;) and not check the browser.

Comment: Guys, check my below answer. Just want to know why data attribute one didn;t work

Comment: use .data('desktopImage'); not .data('data-desktopImage');